# Java Regular Expression for repeated Characters and letters

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a project where i have user Registration form. i want to prevent my users from

1) inputting repeated letters and characters such as `111111` , `wwwwwwww`

2) inputting repeated sequence of digits such as `abc@123412341234` (preventing 1234 from repetition).

I have searched and tried multiple regex but could not find one that can resolve all use cases.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `[math]`? `[automata-theory]`?

Comment: did you want to match `foobar` ?

Comment: What's the minimum length of disallowed repetition? What about "11234", or "ababcd"? Can you give some examples of edge cases?

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*(.+)\1).+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qJ3mB0/1)

```
String[] s = {"111111" , "wwwwwwww","abc@123412341234","fobar"};
for(String i: s)
{
    System.out.println(i.matches("^(?!.*(.+)\\1).+"));
}
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
true
```

OR

```
^(?!(.)\1+$|.*(\d+)\2).*
```

java regex would be,

```
string.matches("^(?!(.)\\1+$|.*(\\d+)\\2).*");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qJ3mB0/2)